# Codeigniter assets folder best practice

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm fairly new to codeigniter, But i'm learning well, I'm going to add a **css, images, js, ...** folder but I'm not sure where to put it

Someone told me to make a 'public' folder

```
system
application
public
    css
    images
```

And then in your index.php ( in the public folder ) adjust accordingly

$system_path = '../system';
$application_path = '../application';

But when I do that i get a 404 ( not the ci 404, but a really-not-found one )

Anyone has any idea what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: This questions is old, I hope you tried the new CodeIgniter 4, it brings some clarity to that particular problem.

Comment: This is 8 years ago. I didn't even know how to spell PHP. I'm in the business still, but using Laravel nowadays. Have a good one!

Comment: This is the beauty of SO!. Every now and then OPs revisit their old postings to update it. I also am using Laravel and I love its Ruby on Rails vibes. Extremely productive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

another angle on this -- and i think what they were trying to tell you to do - is putting your application & system folders one level up from the "public" html folder. that way your source files are not accessible. so like in Mamp the public folder is called htdocs, in most web hosting its called html.

```
 /application/html/
 /system     /html/

 // your main index page is in the public html folder
 /.…..       /html/index.php 

 // an assets folder in the public html folder with css, img, etc folders
 /.……        /html/assets/css/
 /.……        /html/assets/img/
```

then in your index.php, the path is going one level 'up' like

```
$system_path = '../system';
$application_folder = '../application';
```

BONUS - here are two tips that have helped me a lot. 
1) Name your application folder, then you can easily switch between different versions, 
'roll back' very quickly, etc.

```
 /app_alpha/html/
 /app_beta01/html/
 /app_beta02/html/
```

2) Put the base url on the index.php page -- not in the config.

```
   $assign_to_config['base_url'] = 'https://awesomedomain.com';
```

that way you can have a local development version, separate live server version -- and you never have to worry about over writing the base url because its on the index.php page - not in the config.

Answer (score 60):

I have this setup:

```
application
assets
system
.htaccess
```

and in the "assets" folder i have subfolders like "img" or "js" and so on.
I also use "utility helper" to help me point to that folder.

If you want to try it, you have to first create a helper named "utility_helper.php"
with this code:

```
     <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

     if ( ! function_exists('asset_url()'))
     {
       function asset_url()
       {
          return base_url().'assets/';
       }
     }
```

and store it in

```
     application/helpers/
```

then you have to autoload that helper, you go to:

```
  application/config/autoload.php
```

and auto load the helper (example: )

```
  $autoload['helper'] = array('form', 'url', 'utility');
```

you have also to route to that folder ('application/config/routes.php')

```
       $route['assets/(:any)'] = 'assets/$1';
```

and have a .htaccess file with this content:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

now you can simply include external scripts, css example:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo asset_url();?>css/style.css">
```

where css is the folder inside assets and style.css is the css file. 
Like so:

```
   application
   assets
          css
              style.css
   system
```

Comment: If the .htaccess files works the way it does, allowing URLS like /images to be accessed outside the codeigniter system, then why not just put assets there and skip the helper?

Comment: Also, why not include echo in the helper and alleviate the template designer of typing `echo`. Instead they can just write `<? assets_url(); ?>`? (BTW, other than my questions, I very much like this method)

Comment: Well where i'm coding we tend not to write echo this much because you could want to append the function result or something like that.. you're could ofcourse write echo or even use short tag (<?= ?>, if this is new to you, google it :)

Comment: @maetulj Very helpful! Can I ask why did you use if condition i.e ' if ( ! function_exists('asset_url()'))'? Thanks

Comment: @FaisalAshfaq just to check that the name is available altough it should be.  You don't have to do this :)

Comment: I use like @ruzel said, only .htaccess is sufficient.

Comment: This works on my mac book, But on the linux server it breaks,,, No idea why ?!

Comment: should i change the value of 'url'?

Comment: @reggie which 'url' do you mean?

Comment: Nice one so far. However, I've just viewed the page source, and it results this output: `<link href="http://[::1]/dev/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` why was this `http://[::1]` printed instead of the real link? Note that if I click on the output link, the css file really exists and all, but I don't like that the link isn't right

Comment: what will be route syntax for CI 4? for achieving the same?

Answer (score 2):

I would revert back the changes you made to your `index.php`, as it looks to me like they're the source of the problem.

I've been using a similar setup for CodeIgniter, whereby all my images, CSS, and JS go in a folder called `static`, and literally all I did was create that folder and put the files in it, and they worked fine. If you want to remove `index.php` from your URL's, you'll need to make sure that your `.htaccess` file doesn't rewrite the URL's for your static files.