# Codeigniter in localhost MAMP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I am new working in codeigniter . I have downloaded the latest version of codeigniter and install it in localhost. When I run it its working perfect with

```
http://localhost:8888/projects/codeigniter/mr_easy/
```

this url , but when I try to crate and admin like

```
http://localhost:8888/projects/codeigniter/mr_easy/admin
```

it showing "The requested URL /projects/codeigniter/mr_easy/admin was not found on this server."

==================
I have defined this in routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";
//$route['404_override'] = '';

/*admin*/
$route['admin'] = 'user/index';
```

======= in user.php within controller I have put this code snippet

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
}
```

and I have a view login.php

but whenever I run `http://localhost:8888/projects/codeigniter/mr_easy/admin` this url its showing not found.

I am just a newbie in codeigniter , any help regarding why this happening and how could I solve this is appritiable

==================================.htaccess=============================

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /http://localhost:8888/projects/codeigniter/mr_easy/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /http://localhost:8888/projects/codeigniter/mr_easy/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I think you'll find additional information on this [overflow entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820314/codeigniter-assets-folder-best-practice) that will also help you write a helper for dealing with assets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try use .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this . Lets check it I think it will work for you  `http://localhost:8888/projects/codeigniter/mr_easy/index.php/admin`

Comment: Thanks Its working for me but I don't need this "index.php" in between

Answer (score 0):

Try to adding .htaccess in root directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /your local path/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /your local path/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: root directory mean 
http://localhost:8888/projects/codeigniter/mr_easy in mr_easy right ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your URL right, mr_easy is your main folder name? And admin is a controller?

I suggest you just create a Controller named "admin" then create the usual "index" function in it.

example:

> class admin extends CI_Controller {
>       public function index()
>       {  }
>   }

Take note that controller name must be the same with the class name.

Comment: I know it will work but What I need to know that the above thing is working perfectly in server but not in localhost, why this things happens ? because in my site many situation will come where I need to follow this url.

Comment: I have edited my question and add the .htaccess code . Please check

Comment: Hi Ron sorry I wasnt able to check on this immediately. Good thing someone answered it already. :)