# CodeIgniter not loading assets on base install

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm not sure what is happening, but my asset files are not loading in my CodeIgniter application.  In the markup the assets have a path that begins at the base_url so they look like this: "css/style.css" or "js/script.js", and so on.  When the page tries to load the assets are not shown, and instead a 404 error is displayed in the console for each asset, and the page loads with no styles, scripts, or images.  The error looks like this:

```
GET http://www.example.com/css/styles.css 404 (Not Found)
```

Which based on the file hierarchy I have shown below, and the setup I've done in CodeIgniter,  is exactly what they should be set to in order to load.

**Folder hierarchy**

```
root/app/codeigniter/application/myapp1
root/app/codeigniter/system
root/app/www/index.php
```

**CI Setup to make above hierarchy work**

1. config.php - base_url = http://www.example.com
2. .htaccess includes - RewriteBase /app/www
3. index.php - system_path = '../codeigniter/system'
4. index.php - application_folder = '../codeigniter/application/myapp1'

The assets do load when I type the full path:
http://www.example.com/app/www
but that makes for an ugly URL, and I noticed my path change when I load different controllers so the same base template header and footer but for a different controller now has www.example.com/my_ctrl/app/www/css/styles.css and again produces a 404 error.

Can anyone see what I've missed?  I don't remember this happening before, it all just worked.

Comment: Did you set the `base_url` config in `app/config/config.php`?

Comment: try this and let me know the output... `http://www.example.com/index.php/css/styles.css`

Comment: Yah, I have all the config I've set in the list above.  I did base_url, .htaccess, system_path, and application_path.  Do I need to just put <?php echo base_url() ?>/css/styles.css everywhere to make this work?  That does work, but I thought just adding css/styles.css to links was possible.

Comment: So I found this forum post which uses a helper to set the asset url: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820314/codeigniter-assets-folder-best-practice.  It means I have echo the helper function, which is similar to echo base_url(), but it'll do.