# Codeigniter Assets best Method

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to find out best way to load assets folder everytime, rather then loading it again and again from every view.
I have placed my assets folder in root application:

```
/application
/system
*
*
/assets
    /js
    /css
```

I have already tried [Autoload Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820314/codeigniter-assets-folder-best-practice),
and Common method:

```
href="<? echo base_url() ?>assets/css/admin.css"
```

Is there any way to load assets at once?

Comment: Assets don't get "loaded" with autoload.  You have to create a template system so that every time you load a view, the view is automatically inserted into the template.  The template contains the file includes to all of the assets.  Otherwise, using [the examples in the documentation's tutorial](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/index.html), you would put any relevant asset file includes within the `header.php` and/or `footer.php` files.

Comment: Also, for the most secure installation, my `application` and `system` directories are installed _outside_ of the `www` (`public_html`) directory.  My assets are installed _inside_ the `www` directory along with CI's  `index.php` file.