# How to protect ASSETS FOLDER in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I just wanna protect my assets folder in client side. All of my files can access public. I wanna protect it. I have rules `.htaccess` like below, any wrong rules there?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: see this so question it may help [codeigniter-assets-folder-best-practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820314/codeigniter-assets-folder-best-practice)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter assets folder best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820314/codeigniter-assets-folder-best-practice)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do two things

1. via `.htaccess` (Not Tested)
2. via `index.html`

---

### 1. .htaccess

add `.htaccess` inside the assets folder

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

### 2. index.html

Create `index.html` file inside the directory and add this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Directory access is forbidden.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

---

### Output

When some one access outside you get this on browser

> **Directory access is forbidden.**

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper to access these 'assets'. And allow requests to these files only from your server. That's one way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can protect your `assets` or files folder similarly as `CI` protects its application file.
Simply copy `.htaccess` file and `index.html` file from application and paste it to your assets file.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue, My front assests folder was directly through URL.
Add a empty **index.php** file in your folders and it will solve the problem.