# How can I load css or js file in codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

When I am trying to load css or javascript file then it returns 404 error.

I've tried to use helpers such as HTML helper's link_tag, URL helper's base_url methods, it will make a route to the file, but not loadable.

This is my Controller:

```php
class Pages extends Controller{

    public function viewPage($page)
    {
        if(!is_file(APPPATH."/views/pages/$page.php")){
            throw new \CodeIgniter\Exceptions\PageNotFoundException($page);
        }

        helper('html');

        $data['title'] = $page == 'noticeboard' ? "page1" : "page2";

        if($page != "index"){
            echo view('templates/header', $data);
        }

        echo view("pages/$page", $data);

        if($page != "index"){
            echo view("templates/footer", $data);
        }
    }

}
```

My Router:

```php
$routes->get("/", "Pages::viewPage/index");
```

Header in HTML:

```
<?=link_tag('public/css/style.css')?>
```

The assets folder is located in the very root of htdocs(I'm using xampp apache server).

And when I try to load CSS or JS, I get this error:

[image: error message]

I'm completely new to CodeIgniter, so any bits of help would be appreciated.

- Directory structure:

```
htdocs
  -public
    --CSS
     ---style.css
    --JS
     ---app.js
  -app
    --controllers
      ---Page.php
    --views
      ---pages
        ----index.php
```

*** I've changed my CSS, JS file routes from assets to public ***

Comment: Please show us your folder structure then only we can tell you the accurate solution

Comment: @bhuvneshpattnaik Added directory structure.

Comment: What about application folder?

Comment: @bhuvneshpattnaik Added. Application folder has changed the name into 'app' since CodeIgniter 4.

Comment: try replacing `public/css/style.css` to `/css/style.css` in the line `<?=link_tag('public/css/style.css')?>`

Comment: Please check my answer, it might help you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As app is sibling folder of public folder,

And as per codeIgniter 4 .

anything you put in public folder can be accessed directly.

so it should be something like below to get css applied to the view.

In views folder lets say there's a file as index.php

then code should be like below:

index.php

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/css/style.css"/>
```

Comment: If you want to protect your source files from access from outside, you should not put them in the public directory. See details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820314/codeigniter-assets-folder-best-practice

Comment: @bhuvnesh pattnaik I am also having the same issue. Apparently I tried to create assets folder which is same level as app folder and also tried putting the css file in the public folder, it is still showing file not found error.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this**

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://ur_site_url.com/";
```

Than in your view

```
<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css'); ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean 'after that'?

Comment: I mean configure your settings and then in main view use `base_url()`

Comment: This answer is for CodeIgniter 3 not CodeIgniter 4 as CI4 does not use configuration arrays anymore.

Answer (score 2):

GOTO config/App.php and change this variable

```
public $baseURL = 'http://yoursite';
```

then you can access it as

```
<?php echo base_url();?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the html helper and add the stylesheet with link_tag
depending on your setup and if you hide the public folder in your url, you must add public to the url.

```
<?php echo link_tag('public/css/style.css'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add **base_url** in the **application/config/config.php** file? 
Here: http://prntscr.com/pji8a5

Site URL is not defined which you give.

You have given `http://localhost:8080/css.....`

But It should `http://localhost:8080/SITE_URL/css.....`

If you add `$config['base_url'] = "http://site_url.com/";` then you can give direct `base_url('assets/css/style.css');`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css'); ?>">
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/js.css'); ?>"></script>
```

Thanks

Comment: I've changed base_url like this: ```public $baseURL = 'http://localhost';``` (I think it's different because this is codeigniter 4. I didn't had application folder at all), but the error is not fixed.

Comment: What is your project folder name? You should give `$baseURL = 'http://localhost/project_name';` @YJM

Comment: That's CI3 not CI4. CI4 no longer uses $config[] array like that