# CodeIgniter 4 and CI4-Twiggy - load custom CSS file

Tags: twig, codeigniter-4

I am starting out with CodeIgniter 4 and am using https://github.com/noraziz/ci4-twiggy as my template engine.

The documentation is pretty sparce, but so far it is working, with the exception that I am unable to load a custom CSS file when it is not in the **public** folder.

So - setting my CSS file to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
```

loads the file, as it then default looks in the **public** folder. Setting it thus to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../app/Themes/mytheme/assets/css/main.css" />
```

I was expecting that I would be able to load it, but I am not. It keeps giving me a **404 error**. This user had a similar issue, [How can I load css or js file in codeigniter 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58391806/how-can-i-load-css-or-js-file-in-codeigniter-4?rq=2), however, his files were located in the **public** folder, and was not using Twig, so the solution did not work for me either.

I had several other attempts (including removing the **app/.htaccess** file temporarily):

```
{{ base_url() }}app/Themes/mytheme/assets/css/main.css

app/Themes/mytheme/assets/css/main.css

Themes/mytheme/assets/css/main.css    

mytheme/assets/css/main.css

assets/css/main.css

css/main.css

main.css  (after removing the file from **public** folder, of course)
```

Since the template engine is not in the **public** folder, I do not want to move my CSS to the public folder, unless there is no other way without compromising security. Is there?

Comment: "*I do not want to move my CSS to the public folder*" - Then how do you expect browsers to actually download/serve the CSS file?

Comment: Well, I was hoping to not have to split my actual theme file and its assets for ease of maintenance. I hoped there was a way to make that available. For now I have implemented it in the public folder, and it works. I was just hoping it was not necessary :-)

Comment: If you don't want to split the files, you could use a bundler(webpack etc) to serve a combined css-file into the public folder with the partial files sitting somewhere else

Comment: Thank you, Simon. Please post your comment as the answer. That will work for me.